# Generate list of all combinations and maintain index position

Tags: python, list, insert, indexing

I'm looking for a method to generate a list of all combinations with its current index kept maintained:

So far i've been using this method:

```
stuff = ['A', 'B', 'C']
for L in range(0, len(stuff)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(stuff, L):
        a = subset
        list.append(a)
```

which gives:

```
[(), 
('A',), 
('B',), 
('C',), 
('A', 'B'), 
('A', 'C'), 
('B', 'C'), 
('A', 'B', 'C')]
```

What I'm looking for is a solution that gives or can be convertet to the string below:

```
[(0, 0, 0), 
('A', 0, 0), 
('B', 0, 0), 
('C', 0, 0), 
('A', 'B', 0), 
('A', 0, 'C'), 
(0, 'B', 'C'), 
('A', 'B', 'C')]
```

Best,
Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly appending the result, you can generate a new list in the desired format using a list comprehension `[i if i in subset else 0 for i in stuff]`

Here you go:

```
import itertools
stuff, result = ['A', 'B', 'C'], []
for L in range(0, len(stuff)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(stuff, L):
        result.append([i if i in subset else 0 for i in stuff])
```

And now if you check the result,

```
>>> print result
[[0, 0, 0], ['A', 0, 0], [0, 'B', 0], [0, 0, 'C'], ['A', 'B', 0], ['A', 0, 'C'], [0, 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C']]
```